# ListView inside a ScrollView

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Listview inside ScrollView is not scrolling on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210895/listview-inside-scrollview-is-not-scrolling-on-android)

I have a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView` and the problem is that the `ScrollView` is scrolling but `ListView` doesn't scroll. I think this is happening because of that `ScrollView`. Does anyone have a solution for this issue?

Comment: stop arguing about it, it wont solve the question, someone already find the solution, this is the ANSWER by Moisés Olmedo : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210895/listview-inside-scrollview-is-not-scrolling-on-android?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ListView`s have built-in scrolling capabilities. Encapsulate it in any other layout like a `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 6):

I required having a listview inside a scrollview in order to prevent the entire screen from being extremely long.  This allows you have to set the number of items displayed on the list, while the rest will be scrolled.

I use the following class in my app and so far it seems to work terrific.

```
 public class NestedListView extends ListView implements OnScrollListener,
        OnTouchListener {
    private int listViewTouchAction;
    private static final int MAXIMUM_LIST_ITEMS_VIEWABLE = 4;

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if (getAdapter() != null && getAdapter().getCount() > MAXIMUM_LIST_ITEMS_VIEWABLE) {
            if (listViewTouchAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                scrollBy(0, -1);
            }
        }
    }

    public NestedListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        listViewTouchAction = -1;
        setOnScrollListener(this);
        setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        int newHeight = 0;
        final int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        if (heightMode != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            ListAdapter listAdapter = getAdapter();
            if (listAdapter != null && !listAdapter.isEmpty()) {
                int listPosition = 0;
                for (listPosition = 0; listPosition < listAdapter.getCount()
                        && listPosition < MAXIMUM_LIST_ITEMS_VIEWABLE; listPosition++) {
                    View listItem = listAdapter.getView(listPosition, null,
                            this);
                    listItem.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
                    newHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
                }
                newHeight += getDividerHeight() * listPosition;
            }
            if ((heightMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) && (newHeight > heightSize)) {
                if (newHeight > heightSize) {
                    newHeight = heightSize;
                }
            }
        } else {
            newHeight = getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), newHeight);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        listViewTouchAction = event.getAction();
        if (getAdapter() != null && getAdapter().getCount() > MAXIMUM_LIST_ITEMS_VIEWABLE) {
            if (listViewTouchAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                scrollBy(0, 1);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem I have with this solution is that it costs huge amounts of CPU power. In the onMeasure method you are asking the listadapter to recreate every view you ask for, this will make the whole app very slow. I think you should cache the views you ask for and only recreate them when they are invalid.

Comment: While I haven't noticed any problems with this solution on my Atrix, I'm sure it could be a problem on older devices.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following method and enjoy!

```
    private void setListViewScrollable(final ListView list) {
    list.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            listViewTouchAction = event.getAction();
            if (listViewTouchAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
            {
                list.scrollBy(0, 1);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    list.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view,
                int scrollState) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            if (listViewTouchAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
            {
                list.scrollBy(0, -1);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

listViewTouchAction is a global integer value.
If you can replace the line

```
list.scrollBy(0, 1);
```

with something else please share it with us.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't nest a ListView inside a ScrollView.

If you're trying to scroll some other views along with the ListView, you might check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312592/how-can-i-get-my-listview-to-scroll).