# Scroll listview

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I want to scroll listview.But Listview only scrolls when item of listview exceeded the length of screen .But I want to scroll listview whether listview have one item or ten.I have used this code but it's not working,also have searched a lot but there is no tutorial about this found.So please suggest me how to do this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etSearch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="98"
            android:background="@drawable/search_shape"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:singleLine="true" >
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/SearchBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="@drawable/search_selector" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/moreBtn"
            android:layout_below="@+id/etSearch"
            android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >
        </ListView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/moreBtn"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/more_selector"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you show your whole XML file code(BTW whts the need to scroll List when there is only one Item)

Comment: @ChintanRaghwani i have updated my question, have a look.

Comment: see @chintan i want to develop this listview like listview developed in Adobe Flex and listView  of Nokia Lumia.In flex listview if listItem is only one even you can scroll(pull) it up to layout bottom.I hope now you got my requirement

Comment: simply change your listview height to wrap_content
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: i have changed listview layout_height="wrap_content" even its not scrolling...........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found 1 solution, it is called **Pull-To-Referesh**

[How to implement Android Pull-to-Refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583484/how-to-implement-android-pull-to-refresh)

U can download from followin
https://github.com/erikwt/PullToRefresh-ListView (Thanks to Erik Wallentinsen)
But It is not working properly.

So, I made some needed changes to it and prepared one proper working demo.

Comment: Just add your location and email-id to your stack-overflow profile.

Comment: Thank you so much @Chintan .This is what exactly i was looking for .But there is an error when run app Android library project can not be launched.So please suggest me about this

Answer (score -1):

You can try this XML code.

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
   <ListView
   android:id="@+id/listView"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:layout_above="@+id/moreBtn"
   android:layout_below="@+id/etSearch"
   android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
   android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >
   </ListView>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Reason for negative reputation.

Comment: Read my question properly @Bala

Comment: You cannot use ScrollView and ListView together.

Comment: You can refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415011/listview-inside-a-scrollview