# scroll view and list view issue in android

Tags: android

I am adding a scroll view for whole layout. Inside that layout I am adding a lot of view  list view and fixed footer. My list view content is not displaying properly. Its height is very short. Without scroll view it appears correctly. Can anybody tell me what the problem is and how to resolve it? list view is loading dynamically. My xml file is given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


  <ScrollView android:id="@+id/mainScrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:fillViewport="true" android:scrollbars="none" android:isScrollContainer="false">


 <RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">




  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/mainLinear"
  android:gravity="left" >
     <ImageView android:src="@drawable/day2" android:gravity="center"   android:id="@+id/imgDay" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/meetingtimetable2"    android:gravity="center"  android:id="@+id/txtMeeting" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
   <ImageView android:src="@drawable/eventschedule2"   android:gravity="center"  android:id="@+id/imgEvent" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
  </LinearLayout>


   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/mainLinear"
       android:background="@drawable/day3"
       android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:id="@+id/commonLinear">
    <include
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/commonLayout"
    layout="@layout/common"/>
  </LinearLayout>



  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/chkLinear"
  android:background="@drawable/meetingtimetable3"
   android:layout_below="@+id/mainLinear"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/commonLinear"
     android:orientation="vertical">



   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/subLinear"
     android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
     android:paddingTop="10dip"
     android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
    android:gravity="center" >
    <Button android:background="@drawable/meetingrequestrecieved" android:layout_marginRight="5dip"  android:gravity="left"  android:id="@+id/btnMeetingRequest" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" ></Button>
 <Button android:background="@drawable/newmeeting" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="left" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:id="@+id/btnSendNewRequest"></Button>

</LinearLayout>



  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/listLinear"
  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/commonLinear"
  android:layout_below="@+id/subLinear"
  android:gravity="left"
  android:paddingRight="5dip">
   <ListView  android:id="@+id/lstSendMeeting" android:scrollingCache="false"  android:layout_width="300dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

   </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

<!-- footer -->

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:id="@+id/bottomLinear1">
    <include
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/commonLayout1"
    layout="@layout/commonbottom"/>
  </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks

Comment: Punctuate your question. Not able to figure out what you really want

Comment: Why you need ScrollView? No need of ScrollView for ListView.

Comment: I am adding scroll view for whole  relative layout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't add a ListView inside of ScrollView

Check this out [How can I get my ListView to scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312592/how-can-i-get-my-listview-to-scroll)

But seems this guy made it work. Which is Great.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of android:layout_height="wrap_content" because you are setting the height of listview as wrap_content which results in the  listview of smaller size. Increase the layout height or change it into fill_parent ,you will get the desired result